# Replacing 3 same characters of a string with different strings in java using replace()

Tags: java, string, replace

How can I replace 3 same characters of a string with different strings in java using  `replace()`.

```
final String QUERY = "select * from gfc.LSI_ELGBLTY where INSURANCE_ID = ? and SYS_CD = ? and ACCT_TYPE in (?);
```

for example character `?` occurs three times in the above string. How can I replace this character with three different strings using `replace()` function?

Comment: Are you using JDBC? then you can use PreparedStatement. You can set value of your parameters then.

Answer (score 0):

If you use final then you can only assign once

```
final String QUERY = "select * from gfc.LSI_ELGBLTY where INSURANCE_ID = ? and 
SYS_CD = ? and ACCT_TYPE in (?);
```

This is a function you can use to replace a character in a string with thee other characters and return back the modified string

```
String replaceOneWithThreeOther(String str, String firstReplace, 
              String secondReplace, String thirdReplace) {
   String result = str;
   String replace = "\\?"
   result.replaceFirst(replace, firstReplace);
   result.replaceFirst(replace, secondReplace);
   result.replaceFirst(replace, thirdReplace);

   return result; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JDBC you have already ability to do this as below:

```
    final String QUERY = "select * from gfc.LSI_ELGBLTY where INSURANCE_ID = ? and SYS_CD = ? and ACCT_TYPE in (?)";
    Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    try {
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(QUERY);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, firstValue); // setInt or what type you use
        preparedStatement.setString(2, secondValue);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, thirdValue);

        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(QUERY);

        while (rs.next()) {
            // do the read ...
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Or if you want to do this replacement manually, you can do it as follow:

```
    List<String> values = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");

    String QUERY = "select * from gfc.LSI_ELGBLTY where INSURANCE_ID = ? and SYS_CD = ? and ACCT_TYPE in (?)"; // here QUERY is not final

    for (String value : values) {
        QUERY = QUERY.replaceFirst("\\?", value);
    }

    System.out.println(QUERY);
```

The output is :

```
select * from gfc.LSI_ELGBLTY where INSURANCE_ID = 1 and SYS_CD = 2 and ACCT_TYPE in (3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely look into using a [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), if appropriate.

Should you need to perform the replacement yourself, I'm not aware of any built-in capability. However, it's fairly straightforward to roll your own. Here are a couple of versions:

```
static String replaceN(String s, String del, String... rep)
{
    for(int i=0; i<rep.length; i++)
    {
        s = s.replaceFirst(del, rep[i]);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Or a possibly more efficient version:

```
static String replaceN2(String s, String del, String... rep)
{
    String[] parts = s.split(del);
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(parts[0]);
    for(int i=0; i<rep.length; i++)
    {
        b.append(rep[i]);
        b.append(parts[i+1]);
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String q = "select * from gfc.LSI_ELGBLTY where INSURANCE_ID = ? and SYS_CD = ? and ACCT_TYPE in (?);";
    System.out.println(replaceN(q, "\\?", "one", "two", "three"));
}
```

Output:

```
select * from gfc.LSI_ELGBLTY where INSURANCE_ID = one and SYS_CD = two and ACCT_TYPE in (three);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are hard coding the `QUERY` variable, I would suggest tweaking `QUERY` variable a little bit.

Now, the idea is to replace `?` with `{}` with the parameter number inside.

```
final String QUERY = "select * from gfc.LSI_ELGBLTY where INSURANCE_ID = {0} and SYS_CD = {1} and ACCT_TYPE in ({2})";
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(QUERY,"1","2","3,4,5"));
```

This would produce output as

```
select * from gfc.LSI_ELGBLTY where INSURANCE_ID = 1 and SYS_CD = 2 and ACCT_TYPE in (3,4,5)
```